# In React Native, how do you make an interactive tap-and-hold modal like Instagram?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Instagram has a really cool interaction where you can tap-and-hold, aka longPress, on an image and an interactive pop-up appears.  Once it appears you can drag your finger to one of the action buttons and removing your finger applies the action and closes the pop-up.

Here it is in action.
[image: instagram interaction]
And [here's a link to a video](https://photos.google.com/photo/AF1QipOVI5QHpSL5wc8A00TUwwntPOhGeae7mSfFQ0cd) if you need a closer look.

In my app I've got the tap-and-hold popup working, but the finger drag continues to control the underlying View.

**How do you get the finger interaction to transfer to the pop-up?

How do you get the buttons responding to finger drag-over?**

Comment: React native has touch handled components with events as onlongpress. By using this should be able to call another view.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can achieve with `PanResponder`. Using Pan Responder you are basically creating your own touchable components. [Click here for the docs.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html)

Also, you would need the [Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#docsNav) for animating the transitions.